# Show the integration with a complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, harmonic-analysis, complex-integration

I want to show that there exists inverse Laplace transform, $f(t)$ of the function $F(\lambda)$.

In other word, given $F(\lambda)$, existence of function $f(t)$ such that 
$$
F(\lambda)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} f(t)dt.
$$

By Paley-Wiener Theorem, we should show that

there exists $M$ s.t.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F(x+iy)|^2 dy \leq M  
$$
for some $v>0$.

At this stage, i have a question : how to compute of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F(x+iy)|^2 dy \leq M  
$.

If $F(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, how can i compute that integration?

Comment: If $F(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$, then $\lvert F(\lambda)\rvert^2 = \frac{1}{\lvert\lambda\rvert^2}$, so $\lvert F(x+iy)\rvert^2 = \frac{1}{\lvert x+iy\rvert^2} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: What on earth is $v$?